# Get corresponding items from a selected listbox item

Tags: vb.net, listbox, selecteditem, selectedindex

As the title says, Once I select an item from lstordpizza, the corresponding item from lstordserving and lstordqty will be shown from the comboboxes shown in the image. Any help would be appreciated. :)

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of info to my post and I can't think of any way to do this.

When I select 'Hawaiian Supreme', the corresponding item which are 'Family' should appear in the combobox as well as the quantity '9'.

[image: Image Screenshot]

Comment: What have you tried? Need to give more info, like where the data for the next listbox comes from. The term you are looking for is cascading listBoxes

Comment: you got a nicely detailed answer for a pretty vague question - if it helped you with this problem you should click the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

First you need to load the listbox items in the combobox when you open the form with a for each loop.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For Each item As String In ServinSizeLB.Items
        ServinSizeCB.Items.Add(item)
    Next

    For Each item As Integer In PizzaQtyLB.Items
        PizzaQtyCB.Items.Add(item)
    Next

End Sub
```

Then you add a SelectedIndexChanged event to your pizza listbox.
So as soon you select a pizza in the listbox you select the values of the other list-boxes in the combo-boxes.
But first you need to check if there is already a value selected in a listbox.
Otherwise the selection is gone when you select a different pizza.
"maybe i already know the size but i did change my mind about what pizza i want"

```
Private Sub PizzaLB_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PizzaLB.SelectedIndexChanged

    If ServinSizeLB.SelectedItem = Nothing Then
        ServinSizeCB.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If

    If PizzaQtyLB.SelectedItem = Nothing Then
        PizzaQtyCB.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

You should not forget that the first item is at location 0

I don't know if you want them to select the serving size or pizza qty from the listbox or the combobox ... 
but here also the code if its the listbox.

So make a SelectedIndexChanged even for serving size listbox and one for pizza qty listbox.
Becaus the items are in the same order in the listbox and combobox you link the combobox selecteditem with the listbox selected item.

```
Private Sub ServinSizeLB_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ServinSizeLB.SelectedIndexChanged
    ServinSizeCB.SelectedIndex = ServinSizeLB.SelectedIndex
End Sub

Private Sub PizzaQtyLB_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PizzaQtyLB.SelectedIndexChanged
    PizzaQtyCB.SelectedIndex = PizzaQtyLB.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```

And the same you do with the listbox if you select a value in the combobox.

```
Private Sub ServinSizeCB_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ServinSizeCB.SelectedIndexChanged
    ServinSizeLB.SelectedIndex = ServinSizeCB.SelectedIndex
End Sub

Private Sub PizzaQtyCB_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PizzaQtyCB.SelectedIndexChanged
    PizzaQtyLB.SelectedIndex = PizzaQtyCB.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```